# If condition doesn't recognize the value assign to the variable

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I shown a part of my code. i have stored the value of description inside sharedpreferences. when i check the if condition using breakpoint it has the value i want it to have. but when i go throught the flow then the code go inside the else condition. but i want it to go inside the if condition bz description has a value. so  how can i over come this?

```
public static String description = "descriptionKey";
public static String price = "priceKey";
public static String quantity = "quantityKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";

public void run(View view) {

    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("quantity", quantity);
    editor.putString("price", price);
    editor.putString("description", description);

    editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     if (sharedpreferences.contains("description")) {

        description = sharedpreferences.getString("description",
                description);
        quantity = sharedpreferences.getString("quantity", quantity);
        price = sharedpreferences.getString("price", price);
    } else {
        quantity = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
        price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
        description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
    }
```

Comment: Should you check _xxxx.contains("description")_ ? I.e there is a value with key "description" not with key variable _description_ contains.

Comment: What is the type of "sharedpreferences"?

Comment: i have updated my code, can u check it

Answer (score 1):

That should probably be
`if (sharedpreferences.contains("description")) {`

Comment: still it goes inside else

Comment: Why do you have a method `run` with a parameter `View` which writes stuff to SharedPreferences? The parameter is not used and you should pick a name that describes what the method does. Where and when do you call this method?

Comment: I followed this tutorial.. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: You're somehow following that tutorial but I think you don't really understand how it works. The `public static String`s should be final constants, because they hold the key to store and retrieve the preferences. Also the method `run` in the tutorial stores values from textfields when a button is clicked. You have that method but no UI, so I guess you're not triggering that event at all. You should read the Android training on saving key-value sets, the basics are quite clearly explained there: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1):

Change following line

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains(description))
```

to

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains("description"))
```

Hope this will helps you.